# Adding data to window object -

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework

In the webpart I am currently preparing using SPFX I need to assign some user data into window object:

```
(<any>window).userDetails = {
      displayName: this.context.pageContext.user.displayName,
      email: this.context.pageContext.user.email,
      loginName: this.context.pageContext.user.loginName
};
```

However, this.context is getting red marked with the following message:

Property context does not exist on type [component name]

Why is it so?

Note that I have updated all the packages that are originally in package.json to the newest releases (except gulp).

Comment: It looks like a scoping error.  Are you able to provide the rest of the script so we can see what the scope of context is?

Comment: @BigRaj it's just default setup generated by most recent yeoman with the script I enclosed. The only difference is that I updated all the packages except gulp

Answer (score 0):

Mateusz,

I couldn't test the code below, but this is how I would approach it:

```
interface Window {
  userDetails: IUserDetails;
}

declare var window: Window;

interface IUserDetails {
    displayName: string;
    email: string;
    loginName: string;
}
```

Then use the `Window` object as follows:

```
Window.userDetails = {
      displayName: this.context.pageContext.user.displayName,
      email: this.context.pageContext.user.email,
      loginName: this.context.pageContext.user.loginName
};
```

It is arguably more code, but doing so allows you to fully benefit from TypeScript's *strong types*.

A word of caution however: be careful of what information you pass in the `window` variables -- you know, for security reasons.

I hope this helps?